# Extract index numbers from list of string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of strings where those strings have an index in each string and I need to extract the index from that string and put it in a `List<int>`.

Here's is a list example:

```cs
List<string> values = new List<string>();
values.Add("cohabitantGender");
values.Add("additionalDriver0LastName");
values.Add("additionalDriver0AgeWhenLicensed");
values.Add("vehicle0City");
values.Add("vehicle1City");
values.Add("vehicle2City");
values.Add("vehicle3City");
```

from this list I need to extract the indexes from the values `vehicleXCity`.
I have this code right now:

```
public static List<int> FormObjectIndexExtractor(List<string> values, string prefix, string suffix)
{
    var selectedMatches = values.Where(v => v.StartsWith(prefix) && v.EndsWith(suffix)).Select(v=> v).ToList();
    var indexes = new List<int>();
    foreach (var v in selectedMatches) indexes.Add(int.Parse(Regex.Match(v, @"\d+").Value));
    return indexes;
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
List<int> indexes = FormObjectIndexExtractor(values, "vehicle", "City");
```

But if I have a value like `vehicle4AnotherCity` the code will work in the wrong way.

Does anyone have some alternative to this code that may help?

Comment: `values.IndexOf("vehicle2City")`??

Comment: That would work if only `vehicleXCity` values were in the array

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly do you mean by "indexes"? Why would a value like vehicle4AnotherCity work in the wrong way?

Comment: because I may have a value like that in my list and I don't need that integer value (the 4 in `vehicle4AnotherCity`) in my list when I'm searching for `vehicleXCity` values

Comment: Do you want the list `0, 1, 2, 3,` or `3, 4, 5, 6,` in the above case? I.e. the indices that give the positions in the `List<>`, or the digits inside the string? And can `X` be a multi-digit number or not?

Comment: In your code, `.Select(v=> v)` changes nothing and can be left out.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy All you should need to do is update your regex with this `^vehicle\d+\.*?City$` and here is the string interpolation version `$"^{prefix}\d+\.*?{suffix}$"`

Comment: I just tried your code against the example `"vehicle4AnotherCity"` and it worked. What's the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: What do you mean by “it worked”? `vehicle4AnotherCity` is not a value that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static List<int> FormObjectIndexExtractor(List<string> values, string prefix, string suffix)
{
    var s = "^" + prefix + @"(\d+)\.*?" + suffix + "$";
    return values
            .Where(v => Regex.Match(v, s).Success)
            .Select(v=> int.Parse(Regex.Match(v, s).Groups[1].Value))
            .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an extension helper class incase you have a more robust list and you require multiple exclusion options

```
public class INumberList : List<string>
{ 
    public List<int> GetNumberList()
    {
        List<int> numberList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
        {
            numberList.Add(GetIntFromString(this[i]));
        }
        return numberList;
    } 
    public INumberList ExcludeIndex(string prefix, string suffix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
        { 
            if (this[i].StartsWith(prefix) && this[i].EndsWith(suffix))
            {
                //remove non needed indexes
                this.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
    public static int GetIntFromString(String input)
    {
        // Replace everything that is no a digit.
        String inputCleaned = Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9]", "");

        int value = 0;

        // Tries to parse the int, returns false on failure.
        if (int.TryParse(inputCleaned, out value))
        {
            // The result from parsing can be safely returned.
            return value;
        }

        return 0; // Or any other default value.
    }
}
```

Then use like this:

```
INumberList values = new INumberList();
        values.Add("cohabitantGender");
        values.Add("additionalDriver0LastName");
        values.Add("additionalDriver0AgeWhenLicensed");
        values.Add("vehicle0City");
        values.Add("vehicle1City");
        values.Add("vehicle2City");
        values.Add("vehicle3City");
//Get filtered index list with multiple exclusion option
List<int> indexList = values.ExcludeIndex("cohabitantGender","")
                        .ExcludeIndex("additionalDriver","AgeWhenLicensed")
                        .GetNumberList(); 
//will return [0,0,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (using modern C# features) that does not use `Regex`:

```
public static List<int> FormObjectIndexExtractor(IEnumerable<string> values, string prefix, string suffix)
{
  int? TryParseItem(string val)
  {
    if (val.Length <= prefix.Length + suffix.Length || !val.StartsWith(prefix) || !val.EndsWith(suffix))
      return null;

    var subStr = val.Substring(prefix.Length, val.Length - prefix.Length - suffix.Length);

    if (int.TryParse(subStr, out var number))
      return number;

    return null;
  }

  return values.Select(TryParseItem).Where(v => v.HasValue).Select(v => v.Value).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This version splits all the parts of string.

```
public static List<int> FormObjectIndexExtractor(List<string> values, string prefix, string suffix)
{
    List<int> ret = new List<int>();
    Regex r = new Regex("^([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)$");
    foreach (var s in values)
    {
        var match = r.Match(s);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            if (match.Groups[1].ToString() == prefix && match.Groups[3].ToString() == suffix)
            {
                ret.Add(int.Parse(match.Groups[2].ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

or alternatively:

```
public static List<int> FormObjectIndexExtractor(List<string> values, string prefix, string suffix)
{
    List<int> ret = new List<int>();
    Regex r = new Regex($"^{prefix}(\d+){suffix}$");
    foreach (var s in values)
    {
        var match = r.Match(s);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            ret.Add(int.Parse(match.Groups[1].ToString()));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the more generic version.

1. Regex match:

   - starts with 'vehicle'
   - matches a number
   - ends with 'city'.
2. Parse and return as `List<int>`

   ```
       var indexes = values.Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a, @"^vehicle\d+City$")).
                             Select(k => int.Parse(Regex.Match(k, @"\d+").Value)).ToList();
   ```

Comment: But in that version I may get the indexes for `additionalDriver0LastName` from the list and I don't want that if I need the indexes only from a certain value like `vehicleXCity`.

Comment: I've tested and it didn't worked if a value like `vehicle1eCity` exists... it needs to exclude this value and the current code is adding it

Comment: Just take away * from regex

Comment: If I take away the * from the regex then I'm only having 1 as a value (if `vehicle1eCity` is added to the list)

Comment: Check now, I added "Another" as optional.

Comment: I don't think AnotherCity is actually in the list.  It was an example of there being something else present.

Comment: Exactly what @TimRutter says

Comment: So, probably i did not understand the exact requirenment. You would like to include, words that start with 'vehicle' and ends with 'city' and have a number between them?

Comment: Yes or another property with other specifications. In the example I need all the numbers from the values that are named `vehicleXCity` BUT in the list may appear a value `vehicleXAnotherCity` or `vehicleDifferentXCity` that don’t correspond to the match that I need (`vehicleXCity`)

Comment: @Phoenix_uy have you tried my answer?  or the answer of Jeppe Stig Nielsen?

Comment: The updated version matches the last specification.

Comment: @EyIm I think what Phoenix_uy is saying is that if he/she tries to match on City, AnotherCity will also incorrectly match, when they do not want that to happen.  This is because they are using EndsWith which is true for City and AnotherCIty when using the suffix City

Comment: @TimRutter - the regex version matches a number and then city. It will not match AnotherCity. As far as I understand, this is the requirement. :)